# how to override text file data in C++

Tags: c++

I'm creating a hotel management program in C++, but I'm having trouble appending or fixing a guest's already completed info file.

The file is saved as a text file. When the user wants to alter a guest's info, they would tell the program what specifically they want to alter, i.e. name. The program would clear the name, and prompt the user for the first name and surname of the guest. The program then asks the user if they want the info to be saved to the file. If the user says yes, then the file is saved.

**IN THEORY**, the file should just be changed, but what happens, is that a whole new file is created.

```
void AlterInfo()
{
    system ("cls");

    string alter;
    char filename [100];
    ifstream file_ptr;
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\tSaved Members:\n\n";
    system ("dir/b *.");
    cout << "\n\nPlease type the name of the member you\n";
    cout << "     wish to open as it appears above OR\n";
    cout << "     type z (Lower case) to return to main menu: ";
    //cin.ignore();
    gets (filename);

    /*if (filename == "z")
    {
        system("PAUSE");
    }*/

    if (filename[0]  != 'z')
    {
        char saveYN;
        //cout<< "\nPlease enter 6 digit Registration Access Code: ";
        //cin>>RAC;

        //if (RAC == (file_ptr, membershipNumber))
        //{
            file_ptr.open(filename,ios::in);

            // char in_char;
            while(!file_ptr)
            {
                cout << "Member does not exist\n";
                gets (filename);
                file_ptr.open(filename,ios::in);
            }
            getline(file_ptr, name);
            getline(file_ptr, surname);
            file_ptr >> address1;
            getline(file_ptr, address2); // Duplicate required to eliminate
            getline(file_ptr, address2); // empty field bug when using string after integer.
            getline(file_ptr, address3);
            getline(file_ptr, address4);
            getline(file_ptr, postcode);
            getline(file_ptr, telDay);
            getline(file_ptr, telEve);
            //file_ptr >> telDay;
            //file_ptr >> telEve;
            file_ptr >> inDate>>
                inMonth>>
                inYear>>
                outDate>>
                outMonth>>
                outYear>>
                roomNumber>>
                membershipNumber;
            getline(file_ptr, membershipType); // Duplicate required to eliminate
            getline(file_ptr, membershipType); // empty field bug when using string after integer.
            getline(file_ptr, memberNotes);
            GuestForm();
            greentext();
            whitetext();
            file_ptr.close();
            system("pause");

            cout<< "\n\nWhat do you want to alter (ex. name, address, etc): ";
            getline(cin, alter);

            if (alter == "name")
            {
                ofstream myfile;
                resetGuestName();

                GuestForm();
                cout << "\tPlease enter guest's first name: ";
                cin >> ws;
                getline (cin, name);
                GuestForm();
                cout << "\tPlease enter guest's surname: ";
                cin >> surname;

                GuestForm();
                cout << "\tSave these details to a file? <Y/N> ";

                //Confirmation before saving a file
                cin >> saveYN;
                if (saveYN == 'y' || saveYN == 'Y')
                {
                    string saveFileName;
                    stringstream out;
                    out << name << " " << surname;
                    saveFileName = out.str();
                    ofstream myfile;                               //Save file structure
                    myfile.open (saveFileName.c_str(), ios::out);
                    myfile << name << "\n";
                    myfile << surname << "\n";
                    myfile << address1 << "\n";
                    myfile << address2 << "\n";
                    myfile << address3 << "\n";
                    myfile << address4 << "\n";
                    myfile << postcode << "\n";
                    myfile << telDay << "\n";
                    myfile << telEve << "\n";
                    myfile << inDate << "\n";
                    myfile << inMonth << "\n";
                    myfile << inYear << "\n";
                    myfile << outDate << "\n";
                    myfile << outMonth << "\n";
                    myfile << outYear << "\n";
                    myfile << membershipNumber << "\n";
                    myfile << membershipType << "\n";
                    myfile << memberNotes << "\n";
                    //std::remove( myfile);
                    myfile.close();
                    GuestForm();
                    greentext();
                    cout << "\tDetails have been saved\n\n\t";
                    whitetext();
                    system ("pause");
                }
            }
        //}
    }
}
```

I tried just calling my savefile function, but it gave the same results. So I know it's creating a new file with all of the same data, except (in this case) the guest's name.

Comment: This is a weird mix of C and C++. You're using `cout` with `gets` and `getline`. Google `std::string` and `std::cin` instead of `gets`.

Comment: What if a guest's name happens to start with `z`? This code would not allow that guest to be altered. Use `if (strcmp(filename, "z") != 0)` instead of `if (filename[0] != 'z')`. Or else change `filename` to a `string` and replace `gets(filename)` with `getline(cin, filename)` so you can then use `if (filename != "z")`.  Also, your whole "eliminate empty field bug" looks suspicious to me, you should not need to do that if your lines are properly delimited.

Comment: And yes, this code is creating a new file (as it should be). However, I would suggest creating the new file using a temporary filename first, save the data, and then delete the original file and rename the temporary file to the original filename *only if* the save was successful.  Otherwise, if the save fails for any reason, you will corrupt the guest's file.